# Batch - reading from variable

Tags: batch-file

i want to ask how to read from variable? For exapmle:

```
set /p command=
```

I will write:

```
cmd var1 var2
```

So its:

```
command=cmd var1 var2
```

How to make a variable from var1 or var2?

Thanks for answers! :)

205nd,
Batch coder.

Comment: Could you possibly give an example of what you're trying to accomplish? I really don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: I want to select arguments from variable, for example: "ban <user> <reason>" i want to select ban (as identifier of command) and user+reason as argument. Is it possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
set /P command="Enter a Command:"
for /F "tokens=1,2,3" %%a in ("%command%") do (
    echo Running Command %%a
    echo User is %%b
    echo Reason is %%c
)
```

When you run the command:

```
Enter a Command:  ban 205nd unclear
Running Command ban
User is 205nd
Reason is unclear
```

Comment: Yes, helped much! Thank you very much!

Comment: You'd say `if "%%a"=="ban"`